# Using a :reject_if to test uniqueness

Tags: mongoid, nested-forms

I've been using **accepts_nested_attributes_for** with embedded models for a while. For mass assignment and ryanb's nested-forms gem it is practically required. Usually, it is used like this with a lambda function to verify the parameters hash so mass assignment doesn't fail with validation errors (while still being valid) if the user doesn't place any input.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document 
  embeds_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :reject_if => lambda { |c| c[:comment].blank? }
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document 
  embeds_in :user
  
  fields :comment

  validates_presence_of :comment
end
```

What that does, I assume, with the :reject_if is remove the blanks from parameters before validation. What I want to do is evaluate uniqueness as well with validates_uniqueness_of and a lambda block.

I could loop through the comments (self.comments) but I assume there is some better way of doing this. I know that this would also cause uniqueness validation errors to fail silently but I am just wondering how it could be done.

Comment: Have you try a simple `validates_uniqueness_of :comment` in your Comment model ?

Comment: Yes. I want to use :reject_if in addition to validates_uniqueness_of. Using mass assignment, it is possible to create hundreds of entries at once but a validation error will throw the entire assignment. :reject_if strips blank attributes_for from the parameters hash, I want something similar for the uniqueness constraint. (I thought about this yesterday and it could be done with a before_validation callback too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was half way down in the the related column here: [validates_uniqueness_of in destroyed nested model rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772236/validates-uniqueness-of-in-nested-model-rails)

The validation can be modified to not add errors but to reject erroneous data. That will pass the uniqueness validation in the embedded model while stripping duplicates (with a message that that was done).

Comment: How would the validation be modified to simply reject bad data, and not block the rest of the operation?